# Mix Begin With and Ends With Selector in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What's jQuery statement if I want to retreive all elements whose id starting with "abc" and ending with 0-3?

For eg,

```
abc0
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

Comment: Somehow I get a feeling this is the job for a `class`, not a bunch of numbered `id`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('[id^=abc]').filter('[id$=0],[id$=1],[id$=2],[id$=3]')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/m8Lpr/

Comment: If you're gonna do this you could just do `$("#id0,#id1,#id2,#id3")` in the first place...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: That won't do what the question asked for and match for example `abcdef0` or `abc_3`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does what the OP *wanted* to do, his explanation was just a bit vague.

Comment: @Matti, in fact,  my example was misleading while my explanation was correct.What Guffa mention is correct. Thanks both of you.

Comment: @Kai: Aw. Why do you have IDs like this in the first place? Smells like a hack

Comment: Yes.I'm just migrating the plug-in written in pure java script into jQuery plug-in .  So, since I'm using jQuery, it seems like I should change all  of those ways of generating ID too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they're in numeric order in the document, I'd just use `.slice()`.

```
$('[id^=abc]').slice(0,4);
```

And if they have the same tag name, you should include that in the selector, like:

```
$('div[id^=abc]').slice(0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a custom filter function like this:

```
$('[id^="abc"]'.filter(function() {
    return(this.id.match(/[0-3]$/) != null);
});
```

If you really just want the four elements with ids:

```
abc0
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

And, there are no intervening characters between the abc and the digit, then you can just do this:

```
$("#abc0, #abc1, #abc2, #abc3")
```